# Create freehand line with border in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, borders

The linked SVG image below, which I made in Inkscape, consists of a circle filled with a gradient and a freehand line. I'd like to extend the black border of the circle to the freehand line, so that the violet line acquires a thin black border all around it (and it visually proceeds from the circle). What is the best way to do this?

[my image](https://svgur.com/s/WQE)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the freehand line and apply [stroke to path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html):

[image: Stroke to path]

After this, you can apply the desired style:

[image: Final picture]

Comment: Possibly doing a Path > Union after the Path > Stroke to Path.